# Set up automatic log any time click CLI command is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, command-line-interface

I currently use `click` inside my code for setting up plenty of command line tools, but I'd like to run the equivalent of `click.echo("CLI function X was called")` any time function `X` is called. Is there a way to set up this up generally across my project? Or do I have to add this function individually for each CLI function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this and modified [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55634376/3903479) to get a solution. Given this basic click group:

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument("name", default="World")
def hello(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

I added a function that takes a context and invoke method:

```py
def _invoke(self, ctx, invoke):
    command = getattr(ctx, "command", ctx).name
    print(f"Running {command}: {ctx.params}")
    result = invoke(self, ctx)
    print(f"Completed {command}")
    return result
```

I then created a few custom classes that override the `invoke` command to call the above function:

```py
class _Group(click.Group):
    def invoke(self, ctx):
        return _invoke(self, ctx, click.Group.invoke)

class _Command(click.Command):
    def invoke(self, ctx):
        return _invoke(self, ctx, click.Command.invoke)
```

Adding the functions to the existing script is simple, pass the classes into the decorators for the groups and methods with the `cls` argument, i.e.:

```py
@click.group(cls=_Group)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(cls=_Command)
@click.argument("name", default="World")
def hello(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}!")
```

Running the `hello` command now prints to the console before and after the command's execution:

```bash
$ python3 cli.py hello StackOverflow
Running cli: {}
Running hello: {'name': 'StackOverflow'}
Hello, StackOverflow!
Completed hello
Completed cli
```